# Where is the "tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist" in AzureStorage library v2?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

In Windows Azure Storage, we used to do this to create a table :

```
var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(TableName);
```

I just downloaded the last version of the azure storage library (v2), and my previous code doesn't work anymore :

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient' does not
>   contain a definition for 'CreateTableIfNotExist' and no extension
>   method 'CreateTableIfNotExist' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient' could be found.

What is the good code in v2 ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In v2 there's some breaking changes.
Here's the new code :

```
    var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
    // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
    var cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(TableName);
    cloudTable.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Some good inputs :

- How to use the Table Storage Service : in [v1.7](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services-v17/) and in [v2](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/).
- [Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Breaking Changes & Migration Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx) from the Azure Storage Team

Comment: I wrote a blog post on migrating code from storage client library 1.7 to 2.0 which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/17/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-table-storage-code/. I hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing...  My next problem is about Shared Access Signature, because most of samples and doc are about the old API. But I didn't found this on your blog... yet ? :)

Comment: My post was focused more on code migration :) but I can think of writing some more which would focus on other parts including shared access signatures. Do you mind posting your questions about SAS? Somebody here can answer those.

Comment: I have no specific question on SAS for the moment, because I'm just learning how to use it. It's a little bit more difficult with only samples of the old api, but it's on a good way :). Thanks.