# Querying Azure Storage - Code issues

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am having a problem with the first few lines of code that setup an Azure Table Storage Query.

My code is:

```
CloudStorageAccount account;

string CloudStorageAccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

// Create the table client.
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient(); // conflicting

// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people"); // conflicting
```

The third and fourth lines of code (not comments) call the `CreateCloudTableClient()` and `GetTableReference()` respectively. I cannot get these to resolve at the same time.

For the first statement, `CreateCloudTableClient()` returns a `CloudTableClient` from the `WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll`.  The second statement returns a `CloudTable` from the same DLL. However, the DLL does not include a class called `CloudTable`, only the `WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.dll` does, so there is a compiling error on the line that runs `GetTableReference()`.

If I change the `CloudTableClient` assembly to `Storage.Table.dll`, that throws a compile error on `CreateCloudTableClient()`. So one way or the other, I can't get it to work, these two DLLs are fighting. This code is referenced my multiple [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13647480/1168189) so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have tried using `var` instead of the class references but I have the same problem. Somehow the compiler interprets `var` as `Storage.Table.CloudTable` - why? beyond me. I am using the latest version of the SDK (2.7).

Comment: It seems like they are all inside `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`. Perhaps you're mixing old assemblies?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll or Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll?

Comment: Okay. I was getting confused between the two DLLs. I am only using Storage.dll now and it seems to be compiling. Thank you. @YuvalItzchakov please post your comment as answer and I will accept.

Comment: @Paul. Written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.aspx), all the classes you're looking for are in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`.